# How can construct a class from separate standalone functions?

Tags: python, function, class, oop

What are you solution to make a class from this, or how i can use function output from one to another.

get_screenshoot_coordonate , visual locate an img on the desktop, based on input img, and return coordonates, in this case, i store the coordonates in x & y variable. How can use x & y value in move_click() function?

```py
    import pyautogui
    import time
    
    
    def get_screenshoot_coordonate(src):
        try:
            point = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(src)
            x, y = pyautogui.center(point)
            print('coordonate : ', x, y)
        except:
            print("ERROR screenshoot fiind")
            return False
    
    def move_click(x, y):
        try:
            pyautogui.click(x=x, y=y, duration=0.5)
        except:
            return False
    
    def write(w):
        try:
            pyautogui.write(w)
        except:
            return False
    
    
    
    def press_key(key):
        try:
             pyautogui.press(key)
        except:
            return Fals
```

I try to fiind way's to make more dynamic.

```
move_click(23, 1029)
move_click(8, 496)
write("cmd")
move_click(249, 486)
move_click(249, 486)
write("ping www.google.ro")
press_key('enter')
time.sleep(5)
move_click(8, 496)
get_screenshoot_coordonate('img/cmd.PNG')
```

Comment: They don't share a common input. I don't seen any reason to create a class from these four functions.

Comment: Please update your question with examples of how you call `get_screenshoot_coordonate()` and `move_click()`.

Comment: Classes are usually comprised of a set of functions (methods) that all act upon a common collection of data (see [Object-oriented programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming)). It's unclear how that applies here.

Comment: @chepner
For me is important to see another way of tinking,.



I modify the firs post, but there are just test to see if function works.

Comment: That's fine, but you've skipped over "Can a class be used effectively here?"  right to "How do I write a class for these functions?"

Comment: @chepner You can say that about the underlying `pyautogui` module also. Perhaps you should think of the OP trying to create a simplified interface, i.e. an example of the Facade pattern. I am voting to reopen the question.

Comment: @Booboo So what would the facade be wrapping *other* than `pyautogui`?

Comment: Does it *really* need to wrap something else? Maybe tomorrow `pyautogui` will be replaced by something else. If you want to think of it as an adapter class, you could do that do. Or rather, a bridge class.

Comment: By the way, all the functions that return `False` on an exception should probably be returning `True` rather than (the implicit) `None` on success. And `get_screenshoot_coordonate`  (sic) should be returning `x, y`